# An error that is not specified and that I cannot resolve

Tags: genexus

I'm trying to import a design made in Figma into genexus using the GeneXus "Import Design" tool. The application was running normally, only after importing the design the console presented an error and did not specify almost anything, it just stated that some protection was not installed on the server, can anyone help me?[PrintScreen from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx34U.png)

I just wanted some help resolving these errors and making the import work correctly